# Function is not a member of a C++/CX class when using TypedEventHandler

Tags: c++, bluetooth, c++-cx, rfcomm

I'm setting up a Bluetooth server via RFCOMM socket using sample code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm) in Visual Studio 2017. 
When I use TypedEventHandler:

```
auto listener = ref new StreamSocketListener();
listener->ConnectionReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler
    <StreamSocketListener^, 
    StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^>
    (this, &HolographicTestAppMainV2::OnConnectionReceived);
```

with the OnConnectrionReceived function as:

```
void HolographicTestAppMainV2::OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener^ 
listener, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^ args)
{
// Stop advertising/listening so that we're only serving one client
_provider->StopAdvertising();
delete listener;
_socket = args->Socket;
....
}
```

an error message keeps popping up:

> E2161 Invalid delegate initializer -- function is not a member of a C++/CX class

I read through the docs for [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/delegates-c-cx) and it looks identical to what I wrote, which really confused me.

Comment: According to the error message your class is not declared to be a C++/CX class (e.g.: a `ref class`) - though you'll need to show its declaration to be sure

Comment: Also you don't need to `delete` the listener. This is a ref-counted Windows Runtime type.